# How to remove that gray background

Tags: visual-studio-code

This happens everytime with my VSCode, can anyone help me get rid of that gray background color in the className

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBXpX.jpg)

Comment: disable ALL your extensions and try again, locate the faulty extension

Comment: To aid in debugging issues caused by extensions, go to the Extension panel, open the little menu (3 dots, top right), and use "Start Extension Bisect". This will start a debugging process and should guide you through it.

Comment: If that works or you need more detail, I can write up an answer. There is a guide in the blogpost: https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect

Comment: I tried to disable all the extensions, but still has the same problem